# HTTP header for service-to-service calls

Tags: http, http-headers

I have a two services deployed on AWS. Service A calls service B, but service B is also called by other services.
I want to use HTTP request headers to be able to tell which of the calls to service B are coming from service A.
Is there a standard HTTP header that should be used for this?

`Origin` looks like a good candidate, but I am not sure if this rather should be used for calls from the browser only.

Even if the `origin` header would be the right header, I wonder if the "root origin" that initiated the whole communication should rather be present there, e.g. the call from A to B might ultimately is a result of a user/browser communicating with A or even yet another service that then calls A. If that's the case I probably need a different header, cause I really want to know who is the direct caller of B, and not the "root caller" that triggered the communication chain.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using the `User-Agent` header for this if you just want to identify which application (service) made the call. It also allows to track the version of the calling service.

MDN quote:

> The User-Agent request header is a characteristic string that lets servers and network peers identify the application, operating system, vendor, and/or version of the requesting user agent.

MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent
RFC: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110#field.user-agent

If you want to distinguish individual service instances then `Origin` seems to be the correct choice, but consider that it has a very specific syntax:

```
Origin: null
Origin: <scheme>://<hostname>
Origin: <scheme>://<hostname>:<port>
```

MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Origin